# LCD display not working Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, display

I am pretty beginner in Raspberry Pi projects and I was trying to display a 16x2 LCD diaplay module with Raspberry Pi model B+
The LCD module I'm using is named WH160B-YYC-JT#000 
I searched for some online projects and found this on the internet.

http://www.arduinoecia.com.br/2015/03/ligar-display-lcd-16x2-raspberry-pi.html

Translate the page as its not in English.

I've connected the pins as stated in the tutorial and run the code as it is. Only thing I changes was that I didn't connect the Contrast Pin to Potentiometer, but instead shorted it to ground for maximum contrast. But the LCD display is fixed on the following display.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhO4B.jpg

It doesn't change, although the code is running.

Any solution would be helpful.

P.S. I don't have any cobbler pin.

Comment: This is one of the more difficult projects to get working.  You need to get pretty much everything right to get any output.  Double check that all the wires are going from the correct Pi pin to the correct LCD pin.  Be particularly careful with the GPIO numbers.  There are several numbering schemes.  Make sure the one you are wiring against is the same as that being used by your software.

Comment: Yes I double checked all the wrings . Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your lack of properly connecting the contrast potentiometer is not allowing you to see any real character output from the device as well.

Comment: But I've grounded the contrast pin for maximum contrast. I should clearly see the characters.

Comment: I've noticed wit my character LCD displays if I ground it completely it washes out any visible characters.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this tutorial: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/

Using Adafruit's library for LCD will help you a lot, it is compatible with all LCD screens that I have come across.